# How to read the data of generic list without iterate it?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

I have create a list like this:

```
List<int> list = new List<int>();
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(7);
```

now if I want iterate it I should do:

```
foreach (int prime in list)
{
    Console.WriteLine(prime);
}
```

How I can do this with a single line?

Comment: Why do you _need_ to do this with a single line?

Comment: `foreach (int prime in list){    Console.WriteLine(prime);}` `or list.ForEach(prime => Console.WriteLine(prime));` but you'd better don't do so.

Comment: @SonerGönül code improvement I also tried with: `Console.WriteLine(list)` but I get: `System.Collections.Generic.List`

Comment: @EugenePodskal: It can be slightly simpler than that: `list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine)`. Still not terribly nice.

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: In what way is doing it in one line "code improvement" though? What concrete benefit are you expecting to see?

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks, forgot about that.

Comment: @JonSkeet No benefit, I just want to know if there is a way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* do it using [`List<T>.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z):

```
list.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

This employs a *method group conversion* to create an `Action<int>` to call `Console.WriteLine(int)` for each element of `list`.

However, personally I would use the existing `foreach` loop... it makes it clearer that you're expecting a side-effect for each iteration of the loop. Eric Lippert has a [great blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach/) going into details of this philosophical objection.

This code is entirely *safe* - but more "clever", which is almost never a good thing when you're reading code. Ask yourself which code you're more likely to understand *at a glance*.

Note that this isn't accessing the data in the list "without iterating it" as per the question title - it's just that the iteration isn't obvious in *your* code. It's certainly still present in the `ForEach` method.

Comment: The only problem with `list.ForEach` is that I get: `System.Collections.Generic.List`. OT: woah, you have much rep!

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: What do you mean "I get `System.Collections.Generic.List`"? That's just the name of a type. The code should work fine, at least with any modern C# compiler. (It may rely on differences between C# 3 and C# 4 in terms of method group conversions, but that's all.)

Comment: I mean, instead of get `2-3-7` I get `System.Collections.Generic.List`

Comment: @SevengamesXoom: Then you've not copied the code properly. It sounds like you've changed it to `Console.WriteLine(list)` which isn't the same thing at all. The code I've given works fine.

Comment: +1 for suggesting to use `foreach` anyways. I am struggling to think of a good justification to ever use the `ForEach` extension method.

Comment: Well actually I've always used foreach or Linq, but now I know that there is also this way to do it.

Comment: @blins: I might use the `ForEach` extension method if I'd already been *passed* the action in the form of a delegate (e.g. as a method parameter). At that point it would feel natural to pass it on to `List<T>.ForEach` instead of explicitly invoking it myself each time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I give you that could be deemed a reasonable edge case. I guess I just meant that I rarely find myself in a place where I prefer `ForEach`. Another thing that feels odd is that I can't do it (say in aforementioned case) with `IEnumerable<T>` but rather would have to call `ToList()` first.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Also, Eric Lippert's post does a great job of explaining reasoning/philosophy behind why `IEnumerable<T>` extension method does not exist. I guess it has always felt odd in that it is only defined for `List<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ForEach](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
list.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x))
```